# Programming tips to learn efficiently, relaxed, and completing a stressful project for a noob?

Tags: java, android

About 2 months ago I came up with an idea for an Android App however I had no idea how to program except knowing some QBasic and just general programming concepts.

I find it quite ridiculous myself that someone who has no/little knowledge of programming takes on such a large first time project, but I am sure it's a common problem most people who are not programmers have. Most of which probably do not even make an attempt to learn what they need to learn to make their idea come true, and the ones who do, lose ambition shortly after running into consistent problems while trying to make something.

Since I started, I've learned a great deal of Java, PHP, Javascript, HTML, and the Android Development process. I'm always searching on Google, Youtube for tutorials, tips, and using reference guides almost constantly. Whatever that will make my idea come true the quickest.

Just like I had described I still do run into consistent problems and have been since the beginning and only have little to none of my main project completed and still am trying my best.

**So my question to you is what are some tips for someone who is trying to learn as fast as possible to complete their project? Is it just patience? Is it just so ridiculous that it shouldn't be attempted? What kind of mentality should they have? Should they focus on their main project completely or practice on smaller ones?**

Sorry if this is an unusual or dumb question but after putting over 100 hours into learning programming I just don't know if I should be doing this... Thanks!

Comment: Get ready for hundreds of more hours to come! :)

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Comment: Don't worry about the extra readings or practice. Nothing goes to waste, it will help you in future.

And I would start with a big project, but break it up into smaller bites to chew on it better.

Comment: Break your problem into small pieces. Step by step.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for [Programmers.StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think any thing that ask for 'tips' fits in any stackexchange sites.

Comment: If your app is quite large, you should probably create a team to work on it...

Comment: As far I know before going to code it is safe to design and analysis the whole application. Anyway this question is not fit for this site.

Comment: I didn't know people used QBasic anymore. Bravo.

Comment: There is a book, Clean Code, that could teach you something about efficient programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've felt the same way you do right now, and I think it definitely might be due to trying to start too large. I started with big goals to code complex apps and got discouraged after my attempts obviously failed. Once I began acknowledging that there is no way a beginner could code such things (because every skill takes time to learn), and allowed myself to learn at a regular pace, my skills have progressed at a much faster rate! There is nothing wrong with being a beginner, be a beginner.

What I would do is code practice apps that were simple, but each practice app taught me just one new skill. Eventually my apps were starting to get complex, and I hadn't even noticed! Good luck with your coding! If you have any questions feel free to ask!